# Equivalent condition for functional $L$ on $l^{\infty}(G)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $G$ be a group and consider a functional $L:l^{\infty}(G) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $l^{\infty}(G)$ denotes the (Banach) space of all bounded real functions on the group $G$. I have to proof that the following statement:
$$\text{inf}_{x \in G}f(x) \leq Lf \leq \text{sup}_{x \in G}f(x),$$for all $f \in l^{\infty}(G)$, is equivalent to:

\begin{cases}
      Lf \geq 0, & \text{if}\ f \geq 0 \\
      L\mathbb{I}=1,
    \end{cases}
where $\mathbb{I}(x)=1$, for all $x \in G$.

The implication '$\Rightarrow$' is trivial. It's the other direction I'm struggling with. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $g:= f- \inf_{x \in G} f(x)$ and $h:= \sup_{x \in G} f(x) -f$; note that $h,g \geq 0$.  Now, using both conditions, shows that
$$ \sup_{x \in G}f(x) - Lf = Lh \geq 0$$
and similar
$$ Lf - \inf_{x \in G} f(x) = Lg \geq 0.$$